# Selecting overload with tracking reference

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, overloading

In C#, I can have code that does the following:

```
void Add(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, out Vector3 c)
{
  Add(ref a, ref b, out c);
}

void Add(ref Vector3 a, ref Vector3 b, out Vector3 c)
{
  c.X = a.X + b.X;
  c.Y = a.Y + b.Y;
  c.Z = a.Z + b.Z;
}
```

However, in C++/CLI, the compiler is (understandably) not able to select the correct overload:

```
void Add(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, [Out] Vector3% c)
{
  Add(a, b, c);
}

void Add(Vector3% a, Vector3% b, [Out] Vector3% c)
{
  c.X = a.X + b.X;
  c.Y = a.Y + b.Y;
  c.Z = a.Z + b.Z;
}
```

How do I indicate to the compiler that I want it to select the second overload?

Comment: C++/CLI has no syntax for that.  You need to de-tune the native C++ think a bit, value types exist in .NET to make code more efficient.  They should be passed by value, that allows them to be stored in CPU registers.  Doesn't matter anyway, your Add() function will always be inlined by the optimizer.

Comment: If it's that efficient it confuses me that Microsoft's XNA has forms of all their math API's that take vectors and the likes by ref. But yes, I see what you mean, at least when we're dealing with smaller structures like vectors - but what about matrices? Is that still efficient to pass by value?

Comment: Also, does that mean that C++/CLI has no way of using XNA, considering that all the math API's would give ambigious overload errors? (EDIT: I now see I didn't recall correctly; their Vector3 API does not take vectors by ref, but their matrix API does).

Comment: Sure, this is an XNA problem.  They violated a strong .NET design guideline, structs should not have more than 4 members.  Going beyond kills the value of them and you should switch to a class.  Unusual mistake btw.

Comment: Ok, I've made an answer to my question that I will accept tomorrow unless you make one. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It looks like you were wrong, as it is possible to do with interior_ptr (not that I will use it). I have made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant said in a comment to my post, this is not possible. The point of value types is that they should be small enough to be efficient to copy, and if they aren't, they should not be value types. There is therefore no need for the second overload in almost all cases.

EDIT: What Hans said is not completely true. This generates (almost) the exact same IL as what the C# version does (the difference is that it adds a `modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExplicitlyDereferenced)`):

```
void Add(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, [Out] Vector3% c)
{
  Add(&a, &b, c);
}

void Add(interior_ptr<Vector3> a, interior_ptr<Vector3> b, [Out] Vector3% c)
{
  c.X = a->X + b->X;
  c.Y = a->Y + b->Y;
  c.Z = a->Z + b->Z;
}
```